# How Grafana Geomap works with Opentsdb?

Tags: grafana, opentsdb, geomap

I desperately need help. Can someone please show me an example how Geomap works with Opentsdb time series? I am using Grafana V8.1.5.

Here is my query result in Time Series format.

[image]

How can I make it work in Geomap?

I tried to change options in Geomap setting. But no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems geomap doesn't work with Opentsdb. I managed to apply Worldmap plugin (https://www.metricfire.com/blog/grafana-worldmap-panel/) with Opentsdb.

[image]

Even with worldmap panel, I can only use country as location data, no luck with geohash or coordinates.